# Restrict the use of someone running switches against the script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

pretty new to linux scripting but getting the hang of it.
My questions is:

I have created a basic script to encrypt files, I basically want to restrict people running script.sh --help and if they do run anything such as this provide an error.

at the minute if I run the above command it simply executes the script as normal.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Show us this basic script then.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Click "learn more" on the [tag:getopts] tag page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got right your question:

```
#!/bin/bash
ARGS="$1"

if [ "$ARGS" == "--help" ]; then
    echo "I EXIT"
    exit
fi

# DO YOUR STUFF
```

Comment: exactly what I need!